# RPG Bank Change property with method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

so im trying to make a bank for my game , the bank is totalling the value but not changing the property. Why is this? Is it something to do with the scope? Thanks...

ive used your code, im on codepen, when i type console.log(player.credits) it stays as 5000 credits even when i input a new number..

Yes i really like the code you made me, it works, but its still not changing credits when i log it onto the console in codepen...

````
<p id='move'></p>
<input type='number' id='money' min="1">
<button id='deposit' onclick='player.bank()'>Deposit</button>

let player = {
  credits: 5000,
  bankCredits: 100,
  bank() {
    let hope = this.credits || 0;
    let a = parseInt(document.getElementById('money').value) || 0;
    this.credits = hope + a;
    document.getElementById('move').innerHTML = 'You have deposited ' + a + ' and now have ' + this.credits;
  }
  };

console.log(player.credits) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access current object properties inside object functions, you just need to replace `player.credits` with `this.credits`

Also, as you are mainly working with number, you can use `<input type="number"` instead of `<input type='text'`.

```js
let player = {
  credits: 5000,
  bankCredits: 100,
  bank() {
    let hope = this.credits || 0;
    let a = parseInt(document.getElementById('money').value) || 0;
    this.credits = hope + a;
    document.getElementById('move').innerHTML = 'You have deposited ' + a + ' and now have ' + this.credits;
  }
}

console.log(player.credits);
```

```html
<p id='move'></p>
<input type='number' id='money' min="1">
<button id='deposit' onclick='player.bank()'>Deposit</button>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the replies,  ive changed player.credits too this.credits but when i log it to the console it just says 5000 credits still.  Who knows where im going wrong...

Comment: "but when i log it to the console it just says 5000 credits still" can you please update your code to show this issue.

Comment: Ive updated the code as of above,in my first post,  im using your code that you updated.  im on codepen, when i type console.log(player.credits) it stays as 5000 credits even when i input a new number..

Comment: I don't see console.log(player.credits) in your updated code. Is there demo I have added working fine for you?

Comment: The console.log outside will always show the initial value. It does not show the updated value. Updated value is only shown after a change had been made inside bank, you can try to add the console.log inside bank()

Comment: Thank you for your help ive added the console.log to the bank

Comment: just to let you know Zuckerberg ive got it changing because of your advice.  Im new to stackoverflow this is my first day so how do i give you a like?

Comment: No problem at all. Please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour There is an up triangle before the answer, just hit it and you can vote for it. Up Triangle refers to upvote. Also, you can all hit the check mark below it and make it green, to mark the answer as "accepted". Thanks!